# How to configure vsftpd to allow root logins?

Tags: security, login, root, ftp, sles

I'm on SLES 10.1, and trying to configure vsftpd to allow root logins.  Does anyone know how to do this?

So far, I have this:

```
local_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=NO
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.users
```

And I've added root to /etc/vsftpd.users.  When I try to log in, here's what I get:

```
$ ftp susebox
Connected to susebox.example.com.
220-FTP Server (user 'me@example.com')
220
User (susebox.example.com:(none)): root
331-Password:
331
Password:
Connection closed by remote host.

C:\>
```

BTW, if you don't know the answer, please don't bother lecturing me about how I shouldn't allow root logins.  I know what I'm doing, and I accept full responsibility for any ruptures in the space-time continuum that may result.

Comment: Not only are you creating huge dents in the continuum, you're raping the very fabric of it's integrity! The only use I can think up for this is a honeypot, but AFAIK nobody even tries to login with root by ftp. All other uses....http://bit.ly/yzoSbB That being said, it's answered below.

Comment: I have this exact problem but it's in a completely isolated test network. Not all systems are on the Internet, you know.

Comment: I don't see why this fuss is about. I'm setting this up for testing and the server will be wiped out in a couple of days. Using root is the quickest way to get over with my task, why should I makes things overly complicated, because somebody told me this at school?

Answer (score 17):

DISCLAIMER:   Enabling root login for FTP is a ***Very Bad Idea*** for many, many reasons.

Edit your  **`vsftpd.conf`**  file, and add the following line:

```
userlist_deny=YES
```

Edit  **`user_list`**  and  **`ftpusers`** and comment out "root".

Comment: Just FYI for those using vsftpd, the user_list file is located under /etc/vsftpd/user_list

Comment: Fedora 20: I had to change it in both places: user_list and also ftpusers.

Answer (score 14):

For those (like me) using VSFTPD on Ubuntu server in mid-2013, it appears that root is allowed to login via secure ***SFTP*** by default, no special changes necessary.

However, if you really need plain old ***FTP*** access, all I had to do was:

```
sudo nano /etc/ftpusers
```

And comment out the line with `root` on it by placing a `#` at the start.  Save the file, and reloading the server is not even necessary.

**BEWARE:** This potentially allows the root password to be transmitted over the network, completely unencrypted, in PLAIN TEXT. It's a very bad idea unless you're working on a local virtual machine.

Answer (score 4):

`vi /etc/pam.d/vsftpd` -> if you use vsftpd

find

```
auth blablabla sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers
```

Make it to be `sense= allow` or you can  uncomment `script` above it, or modify the file:ftpusers or add another ftpusers files

Answer (score 1):

for Debian 8 Jessie, you just need to edit `/etc/ftpusers` and comment out or delete root. nothing else needed, just restart vsftpd

Answer (score 0):

Vsftpd can use pam for authentication, so I suggest you check /etc/pam.d/vsftpd. You will probably find it is pam that has been configured to prevent root from logging in.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions, you may need to change `pam_service_name=vsftpd` to `pam_service_name=ftp` near the end of your `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file.  Otherwise, you may get a login authentication error for root (or any user) even though permissions are otherwise correct.

Answer (score 0):

As 2020, after a fresh install of vsftpd, the only step required is changing /etc/ftpusers from:

```
root
daemon
bin
sys
adm
...
```

To

```
#root
daemon
bin
sys
adm
...
```

The ftpuserlist file explicitly lists users that are disallowed FTP access.

Also,

1. If you're using software controlled firewall(Like UFW or IPTables), make sure to open the FTP ports and also configure VSFTPD passive mode:

   pasv_enable=Yes 
   pasv_max_port=10100 
   pasv_min_port=1009 
   pasv_address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

   You should select a port range that fits your network/needs, then, afterwards allow this port range on your firewall, otherwise you'll keep getting a constant '227 Entering Passive Mode' followed by a disconnection.
2. If you're using Amazon EC2, Google Cloud, Azure or any other solution, make sure to also allow those ports on the Security Groups/Firewall Rules on the console.